# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.3.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Failed to resolve: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.3.0`
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Failed to resolve: `com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.3.0`
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

tried changing CompileSdkVersions,targetSdkVersions

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.teknopc.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.3.0'

    implementation('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.8@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.8@aar')
    implementation 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'

    implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:2.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-integration:2.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.3.0'

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/journeyapps/maven"
    }
}
```

Comment: `implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'`

Answer (score 2):

There is no `28.3.0` version of support libraries. Try using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0` `com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0`.

**Note** : `28.0.0` is the last update in support libraries. All the future updates will be in `androidx` libraries.